# Creating a function in Postgresql that does not return composite values

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

I'm learning how to write functions in Postgresql. I've defined a function called `_tmp_myfunction()` which takes in an `id` and returns a table (I also define a table object type called `_tmp_mytable`)

```
-- create object type to be returned
CREATE TYPE _tmp_mytable AS (
    id      integer, 
    cost    double precision
    );

-- create function which returns query
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _tmp_myfunction(
    id    integer
    )
RETURNS SETOF _tmp_mytable AS $$
BEGIN  
  RETURN QUERY 
  SELECT
    sales.gid,
    cost  
  FROM 
    sales
  WHERE
    id = sales.gid;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This works fine when I use one `id` and call it using the following approach:

```
SELECT * FROM _tmp_myfunction(402);
```

[image]

What I would like to be able to do is to call it, but to use a column of values instead of just one value. However, if I use the following approach I end up with all values of the table in one column, separated by commas:

```
-- call function using all values in a column
SELECT _tmp_myfunction(t.id)
FROM transactions as t;
```

[image]

I understand that I can get the same result if I use `SELECT _tmp_myfunction(402);` instead of `SELECT * FROM _tmp_myfunction(402);` but I don't know how to construct my function in such a way that I do not get composite values when I pass in a column of values.

Comment: Just updated my variable names to make this a little clearer (I had changed them to make my question clearer and missed that there would be a conflict).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter While you can call a set-returning function in `SELECT`, the behaviour can be truly bizarre. It's a legacy PostgreSQL specific hack that should be abandoned as soon as PostgreSQL 9.3's `LATERAL` is available for use. For just how weird, compare `SELECT generate_series(1,3), generate_series(1,3);` to `SELECT generate_series(1,3), generate_series(1,4);` . The 1st returns three rows, pairs of results in order. The second returns *twelve* rows, all possible pairings of results, like a cross product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like that:

```
SELECT (t2.function_row).id,
       (t2.function_row).cost
FROM (SELECT _tmp_myfunction(t.id) as function_row
     FROM transactions  t ) t2;
```

It will give you the fields, instead of composite rows.

Comment: Note that PostgreSQL may execute the function repeatedly for each row, once per `(func_row).column`. Add a `RAISE NOTICE` to the function to see what I mean. 9.3's `LATERAL` support should finally fix this. There's a depesz article with detail and examples, I just can't seem to find it at the moment.

Comment: @Craig: [You probably mean this one.](http://www.depesz.com/2012/08/19/waiting-for-9-3-implement-sql-standard-lateral-subqueries/) Looking forward to the feature, too.