# If possible, how can I use a column definition list when I want to use the result of a record returning function in the select target list?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a simple table with some ids and I am doing this query:

```
select funA(t.id), funB(t.id) from customers t
```

which properly returns 2 columns with the records. Functions funA and funB RETURN record.(not a defined record type)

Now, I want to get all the record columns of both the functions instead of the 2 record columns:

I know I can use a column definition list when I am calling the function in the FROM clause, but here I am calling the functions in the select list. Is it possible to supply the column definition list somehow, when I want to use the function call in the SELECT list?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT (sub.funA_result).field1,
       (sub.funA_result).field2,
       (sub.funB_result).field3,
       (sub.funB_result).field4
FROM (SELECT funA(t.id) as funA_result,
             funB(t.id) as funB_result
      FROM customers t) sub
```

Also you can find some details in my answer to this similar question: [Creating a function in Postgresql that does not return composite values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810812/creating-a-function-in-postgresql-that-does-not-return-composite-values)

Comment: it doesnt work. Probably because it is not a registered record type. The error message is: "missing FROM-clause entry for table "funA_result", which is understood since the outside select sees the result with the "sub" alias. you probably meant (sub.funA_result).field1 ... which gives the correct error: "record type has not been registered"

Comment: Also, after looking at the question you mentioned, I see the issue, but my functions are not set-returning ones, but record returning. Maybe postgres considers them equivalent in the sense that a record is a set with one record.

Comment: @Paralife The malual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html) says the same, I told you. Can you show me the function code?

Comment: it will be difficult since funA and funB perform rather too much stuff to put here. The main concept is that based on customer ID, these two functions produce a record that is not directly contained in any table. They are on the fly calculated records. FunA and FunB for the sake of my problem, are guaranteed to produce each one a dynamically structured record and so cannot be predeclared as a type. I just want to find a way to output a select list with their columns expanded. I am leaning towards leaving it as it is (2 record columns) and merging them in the app level...

Comment: @Paralife Can you `CREATE TYPE` for your functions to return some defined type instead of general record?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21562/discussion-between-paralife-and-igor-romanchenko)